# Can't compile RxCocoa for Apple Watch

Tags: swift, apple-watch, rx-swift, watchos, rx-cocoa

I've been trying to compile an already existing iOS project containing a target for an Apple Watch extension.

The project uses RxSwift/RxCocoa which, reading at the official documentation, is compatible with watchOS.

The project compiles and runs successfully on Apple Watch simulator, but it fails on a real Apple Watch, with the following error:

```
Cannot find 'CGRectType' in scope
Cannot find 'CGPointType' in scope
Cannot find 'CGSizeType' in scope
```

The reason of this is that these three constants, declared in a class extension inside RxCocoa, are declared like this:

```
#if arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64)
    let CGRectType = "{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}"
    let CGSizeType = "{CGSize=dd}"
    let CGPointType = "{CGPoint=dd}"
#elseif arch(i386) || arch(arm)
    let CGRectType = "{CGRect={CGPoint=ff}{CGSize=ff}}"
    let CGSizeType = "{CGSize=ff}"
    let CGPointType = "{CGPoint=ff}"
#endif
```

Do you know if there's any way to make it work, as this library is supposed to be compatible with watchOS?

Comment: Which is the version of the rx library that you are using? Which version of the watchOS are you targeting?

Comment: I've tried with RxSwift 6.0.0 RC1 and watchOS 7. When I downgraded to RxSwift 5 it seems to be working, even if now I have other compilation issues and don't know yet for sure if it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are still using am old version of the library (not compatible with recent version of the watchOS)

The right definition on the library should be something like

```
#if arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64)
    let CGRectType = "{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}"
    let CGSizeType = "{CGSize=dd}"
    let CGPointType = "{CGPoint=dd}"
#elseif arch(i386) || arch(arm) || arch(arm64_32)
    let CGRectType = "{CGRect={CGPoint=ff}{CGSize=ff}}"
    let CGSizeType = "{CGSize=ff}"
    let CGPointType = "{CGPoint=ff}"
#endif
```

According to this two discussion thread in the library site

[Fix build for new arm64_32 architecture](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/pull/1740/files/dbfcf3cd4573f0ae7183df5f27b8853a3102e819)

[Xcode 10 GM: Use of unresolved identifier 'CGRectType'](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1737)

It should be fixed in the latest version of the library

Comment: Actually I've got problems with the latest version of the library 6.0.0 RC1 and when downgraded to 5.0.0 it worked... well now I have other issues, but not that one

Comment: @LuigiTrevisi happy to hear if you find any other issues. Thanks !